# Illustrator: trying to use the vertical type tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, typesetting

I am trying to type vertical text however just it comes out rotated.

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAAU7.png
still same

Answer (score 1):

- select your text object
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the 'Character' panel
- tick 'Standard Vertical Roman Alignment' from the top right flyout menu

[image]